# Why does the code stop executing after the while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop, doubly-linked-list

I was doing a doubly linked list but I found out that when I print nodes in reverse order, the code doesn't work. It seems like stuck by the previous while loop.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct LLNode
{
    char name;
    struct LLNode *left;
    struct LLNode *right;
};

struct LLNode * createNode (char data)
{
    struct LLNode *temp; temp = (struct LLNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct LLNode));
    temp->name = data;
    temp->left = NULL;
    temp->right = NULL;
    return(temp);
};

int main()
{
    struct LLNode *curr=NULL;
    struct LLNode *head=curr;

    head = curr = createNode ('A') ;
    printf ("curr->name = %c\n", curr->name) ;

    printf ("head %c tail %c\n",head->name,curr->name) ;

    curr->right = createNode('B');
    printf ("curr->right->name = %c\n", curr->right->name) ;

    curr->right->left = curr,
    printf ("curr->right->left->name = %c\n", curr->right->left->name) ;

    curr = curr->right;
    printf ( "curr = %c\n" , curr->name) ;

    printf ("head %c tail %c\n",head->name,curr->name) ;

    curr->right = createNode('C');
    printf("curr->right->name = %c\n",curr->right->name);

    curr->right->left = curr;
    printf("curr->right->left->name = %c\n", curr->right->left->name);

    curr = curr->right;
    printf("curr->name= %c\n",curr->name);

    printf ("head %c tail %c\n",head->name,curr->name) ;

    printf ("Linked list from head to tail: ");

    while (curr!= NULL)
        {
            // Print nodes from beginning to end.
            printf("%c ", head->name);
            head = head->right;
        }

    printf ("Linked list in reverse: ");

    while (curr!= NULL)
        {
            // Print nodes in reverse order.
            printf("%c ", curr->name);
            curr = curr->left;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The code seems to stop after executing the while loop "Print nodes from beginning to end", but I don't know why. I've tried to use break, continue and other methods but still cannot solve this problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: There are three compiler warnings about non-matching levels of indirection. Please check them out. Lines 23, 42, 51.

Comment: You only seem to be setting `curr->right`. Why are you not setting `curr->left` values? You won't be able to traverse backwards

Comment: Please note that this site isn't a live dialogue for finding all the bugs in your code. The preferred method is to use a debugger :)

Comment: Oh, I'm a new C learner, but I didn't hear debugger before, I will try to learn that too, thanks for your advise! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your code. Apart from not setting `curr->left` values. I think the way you're iterating over your linked list; head would be `NULL` at the end of first iteration and control won't come inside reverse printing loop. You would need to break out of loop without moving the head when you reach `curr->left == NULL` or `curr->right == NULL` depending upon you're traversing forward or backward.

I made some code changes to your code and I was able to see desired output:

```c
int main() {
    struct LLNode *curr=NULL;
    struct LLNode *head = curr;
    struct LLNode *prev = NULL;

    // Insert first Element
    head = curr = createNode ('A') ;
    printf ("curr->name = %c\n", curr->name) ;

    // Insert Second Element
    curr->right = createNode('B');
    printf ("curr->right->name = %c\n", curr->right->name) ;

    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->right;
    printf ( "curr = %c\n" , curr->name) ;

    // Insert Third Element
    curr->right = createNode('C');
    curr->left = prev;
    printf("curr->right->name = %c\n",curr->right->name);

    prev = curr;
    curr = curr->right;
    curr->left = prev;
    printf("curr->name= %c\n",curr->name);

    printf ("\nLinked list from head to tail: ");
    while (1) {
        // Print nodes from beginning to end.
        printf("%c ", head->name);
        if (head->right == NULL)
            break;
        head = head->right;
    }

    printf ("\nLinked list in reverse: ");
    while (1) {
        // Print nodes from beginning to end.
        printf("%c ", head->name);
        if (head->left == NULL)
            break;
        head = head->left;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I was able to see list getting printed correctly:

```
curr->name = A
curr->right->name = B
curr = B
curr->right->name = C
curr->name= C

Linked list from head to tail: A B C 
Linked list in reverse: C B A
```

Comment: Oh, so it's different to write `curr->right->left` with `curr->left`, I think that's the point why I can't run the code just now. Thank you very much because it took me hours to find out why my code didn't work.